# How to set parameters for mapbox geocoder so that it only returns zip codes?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, zipcode, geocoder

I'm currently working with a map and I only want my users to be able to search by their own zip code. Is it possible to customize the functionality of it in this way? here is the only code I'm working with for it:

```
'map.addControl(
    new MapboxGeocoder({
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
    mapboxgl: mapboxgl
    })
);'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the returned types by using the `types` property to values defined here: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#data-types

```
map.addControl(
    new MapboxGeocoder({
        accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
        mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
        types: 'postcode'
    })
);
```